# Android Studio: The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, ros

I know that there are some similiar questions to this one but I've tried the suggestions that I found in the asnwers but none of them worked for me so I decided to publish my version of the problem.

I'm using this android studio project https://github.com/rosjava/android_core that has multiples modules inside as you can see. I had another project that I had to import to this android_core one so I downgraded its graddle version, since the version was more updated, and added it as an imported module.

After I fixed some building problems I got the "Default Activity not found" error which seemed odd to me since I had an activity marked to be the default activity so either way I decided to add it here too:

[image: Specified Activity]

The next warning is the one on the bottom of the image which, once again, sounds odd to me since I had everything declared in the oringal project's AndroidManifest.xml file it's exactly the same on this one:

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

I have tried re-building, Invalidating Cache/Restarting and deleting and re-extend the AppCompactActivity class but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm also stuck on exactly this. Did you advance or resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the manifest xml should be a manifest node with an attribute package. Make sure that the package 'com.example.prj_' is the value.

Then in your activity node you only have to place the value '.MainActivity'. Otherwise you can get some build errors for the resources in the R class.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prj_">

    <application
        ...>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: the manifest node has that package attribute!  Sorry for not showing the full content but I still get the same error

Comment: Is the activity name  value  in the manifest then ".MainActivity" or is  it "com.example.prj_.MainActivity"? It should be the first.

Comment: I've changed it to ".MainActivity" and the error is still the same

Comment: The package attribute was deprecated but the problem persists, so this answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add .MainActivity to your Android Manifest file.

```
<application
    ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are apparently race conditions with background computation of the merged manifest vs. automatic checks of it. The workaround would be to open `AndroidManifest.xml` and click on `Merged Manifest`, this forces the merge. Then clicking `Run` should pass the automatic tests.

See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158019870

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to clean a project for removing this **error**.

```
1- File-> Sync Project with Gradle Files 

2- Files -> invalidate cache / Restart

3- android:name=".MainActivity" -->  android:name="com.example.prj.MainActivity"
```